# How to write a double type into file in c/c++ in windows?

Tags: c++, syntax

```
double Time;
...
WriteFile( tmp_pipe, Time, sizeof(double), &dwWritten, NULL );
```

The above reports :

```
error C2664: 'WriteFile' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'double' to 'LPCVOID'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `&Time`, not `Time`, for parameter 2 of the function call.

Comment: Thanks,do you know what `LPC` means in `LPCVOID`?

Comment: Long Pointer Const Void ? - basically a pointer to any data type.

Comment: Long Pointer to a Constant void type.  Basically just a pointer to constant data of any kind.  Link:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383751(VS.85).aspx

Comment: But `Time` isn't a constant in my case,how?

Comment: @user198729, in this case the function is indicating that it will not modify the contents of your buffer.  As far as `WriteFile` is concerned, the data is constant.  You don't need to worry about it changing during the call.